# how to display list of updating files in p4v

Tags: perforce, p4v

While I sync code using p4v client, the Log window does not show the list of files which are updated. Is there any way to do that? p4win client does show the list though.

Thank you.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Go to "Edit>>Preferences" menu. On the "General" tab under the "Log options" section, check "Show p4 command output for file operations".

Comment: It's now "Edit->Preferences" under Logging. The "General" tab is gone.

Comment: Hi, could you please help. I wonder is it possible to see pending files to be updated and manually choose which of those to update? (I'm using MyEclipse and there is an option "synchronize with depot" which is too slow (very big project), when i use p4v to update it is very fast, now i'm trying to see pending updates and update only necessary parts... I'm new to p4.

Answer (score 8):

@Almo

For newer version

Edit->Preference->Logging
in right panel under "Log Pane Options", check "Show p4 command output for file operations"

Answer (score 4):

Edit->Preference->Logging in right panel under "Log Pane Options", check "Show p4 command output for file operations"